# Rotate rectangle around its own center in SVG

Tags: svg

I have following piece of code :

```
<svg>

<defs>
<rect id = "myRect"
      x = "10"
      y = "10"
      height = "120"
      width = "120"
      stroke-width = "2px"
      stroke = "red"
      fill = "blue" />

</defs>


<g transform = "translate(100,30)">
  <use xlink:href = "#myRect" />
</g>

<g transform = "translate(100, 100) rotate(45 ? ?)">

  <rect id = "myRect"
      x = "10"
      y = "10"
      height = "120"
      width = "120"
      stroke-width = "2px"
      stroke = "green"
      fill = "yellow" />
</g>

</svg>
```

When I translate rectangle without rotation, it is working fine. But when I rotate it, I wanted to rotate it around its center axis point. What should I need to pass to rotate attribute?

Comment: Having two elements with the same id (myRect) will cause trouble.

Comment: Note: you can use `transform-origin` as an alternative. It is the point around which a transformation (rotate, translate, scale, skew) is applied.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You just need to add half the width/height of the rectangle to get its centre.

```
<g transform = "translate(100, 100) rotate(45 60 60)">
```

See [transform documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) of the rotate function for more information.

Comment: As a note, the syntax is `rotate(degree x y)`, so it is not "half width/height" if your rectangle is e.g. centered on 100x100 viewBox then it's trivially `rotate(45 50 50)`.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, you can apply the `transform` attribute directly to the `<rect/>` element, you don't need to use a `<g/>` (group) if you only have one shape. I'm still new to the SVG standard, and this wasn't immediately obvious to me, maybe it'll save someone some time.

Comment: Also, something that helped me, is if your svg says `viewBox="0 0 23 19"` then you must divide in half such as this: `transform="rotate(180 11.5 9.5)` to flip it upside down.

Answer (score 146):

You would have to set the center as the center of the filled element. Like this:

```
svg .rotate {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: `transform-box: fill-box`: thanks for saving my day.

Comment: I got mine to work (a line in an SVG) with `transform-origin: 32px 40px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);`. I needed to remove `transform-box` and 32 is the center of the line in X and 40 is the bottom in y (it's a vertical line rotated from the bottom)

Comment: @vinay-bagale this should be the accepted answer ;)

Comment: "transform-box: fill-box" was what I've been missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome. I often rotate animation with Image. SVG need this to rotate in right way. Thank you.

Comment: For me it worked after removing `transform-box`, but adding `transform-origin`

Answer (score 39):

The accepted answer works if you are drawing the rectangle starting at point (0,0) *which was the OP case*. However for me it was not!

Here is what worked for me:

- To get the rectangle coordinates i used `$('#rectID').getBBox()`
  method, should return [**rect-height , rect-width , rect-y , rect x** ]
- The center point is ( rect-x + (rect-width/2) , rect-y + (rect-height/2) )

Here is a snippet i used on the browser console:

```
var coord = $('#elemID')[0].getBBox();
coord.x + (coord.width/2) +' '+ coord.y + (coord.height/2)
```

Comment: The OP doesn't even mention that this will be displayed in a browser, what does javascript have to do with anything? Let alone jQuery…

Answer (score 9):

origin
`x = x + width / 2`
`y = y + height / 2`
here
x is 10
y is 10
width is 120
height is 120

```
<g transform = "translate(100, 100) rotate(45 70 70)">
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer was the answer that helped me understand this best!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but if there are people out there who are looking make the values modifiable outside the group element

```
    const centerX=100;
    const centerY=100;
    const firstAngle=45;
    const secondAngle=60;
    const thirdAngle =60;
  
    <g transform ={`translate(${centerX}, ${centerY}) rotate(${firstAngle} ${secondAngle}, 
    ${thirdAngle})`}>
```

Answer (score -16):

Nothing you just need to write the following code with the element in javascript:

```
element.rotate(angle Degree);
```

Comment: What is `element` in your example? SVGElement does not have a `rotate` method.