# svg dashed line circle animate so it rotates

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG that looks like this,

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1130" height="1130">
    <g fill="none" stroke="#1864ab" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4" opacity=".4"> 
        <circle cx="565" cy="565" r="565" stroke="none"/>
        <circle cx="565" cy="565" r="564"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want to give the impression that the this circle is spinning clockwise I can not for the life of me figure it out, I have in the past done stroke animation where one stroke gets painted one after the other so the svg looks like it's being drawn, but I have never animated the rotation of an svg.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138801/rotate-rectangle-around-its-own-center-in-svg

Answer (score 1):

Or with [SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1130" height="1130">
    <g fill="none" 
       stroke="#1864ab" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4" opacity=".4"> 
        <circle cx="565" cy="565" r="565" stroke="none"/>
        <circle cx="565" cy="565" r="564"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="360 565 565"
                          to="0 565 565"
                          dur="4.1s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting an `animation` in which it starts at `360deg` and works to `-360deg` to get the clockwise rotation. See the example below.

```css
@keyframes rotation {
    0%{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
    100%{ transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
svg {
  animation: rotation 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1130" height="1130">
    <g fill="none" stroke="#1864ab" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4" opacity=".4"> 
        <circle cx="565" cy="565" r="565" stroke="none"/>
        <circle cx="565" cy="565" r="564"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```